# Karpov-Kasparov matches prearranged?

Tags: fischer, kasparov, karpov

In an interview toward the end of his life, among other (questionable) things, Fischer claimed that the Karpov-Kasparov matches were prearranged.

Is there any evidence to support this idea or was it likely another of Fischer's delusional conspiracies?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No evidence to support this**

It's hard to prove a negative, but I've seen a lot of coverage of Karpov-Kasparov and none of them even hinted that the matches were pre-arranged. Fischer is the only person who thought that way. Most other people loved the high-quality chess the matches produced ([example](https://www.chess.com/article/view/karpov-vs-kasparov-world-chess-championship-1987)).

Comment: In addition to this, Karpov and Kasparov had differing political views (in the USSR mind you) and also despised each other to an extent. I believe Kasparov even wrote a book in the 80s trashing Karpov or something. In any case, the greatest series of world championship matches was almost certainly not fixed; this stuff maybe(?) happened in the 50s, but not the 80s.

Answer (score 0):

Close to Fischer's death he had a somewhat candid interview with someone. I can't remember sorry. If my memory serves me he was giving the interview on the plane to Iceland. The interviewer asked his opinion about certain chess players.

Kasparov was the only one that Fischer respected. When asked about Garry he gave an answer with very strong body language that Kasparov was strong in his opinion. Its possible Bobby was just mouthing off about the matches or mouthing off at the Soviets.

I'm kinda like that myself with Communists or any aggressive form of governance. I tend to think of powerful party members more akin to the mob that would not hesitate to fix the matches if it would make them money and I think Bobby was just pulling everyone's leg. The interview was on YouTube as late as 2013. It might be archived by now. If Bobby really thought the matches were fixed I doubt he would have a good opinion about Garry's chess. This would be akin to Fisher ranting about Jews when he knew full well since early memory he was a full Euro-Jewish descendant.

I hope that the YouTube video is still there because it is worth watching and Fisher was very normal behaving and polite enough not a ranting madman. The beard he wore might make some think so but I digress.